# gazebo spawn_model from .py source code

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn-model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

env: Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Indigo.
Is there a way to spawn models from the code?
I was referring to [gazebo_msgs/SpawnModel.srv](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/gazebo_msgs/html/srv/SpawnModel.html). Tried,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy, tf
from gazebo_msgs.srv import DeleteModel, SpawnModel
from geometry_msgs.msg import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Waiting for gazebo services...")
    rospy.init_node("spawn_products_in_bins")
    rospy.wait_for_service("gazebo/delete_model")
    rospy.wait_for_service("gazebo/spawn_model")
    print("Got it.")
    delete_model = rospy.ServicePoxy("gazebo/delete_model", DeleteModel)
    spawn_model = rospy.ServiceProxy("gazebo/spawn_model", SpawnModel)
    
    with open("$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH/product_0/model.sdf", "r") as f:
        product_xml = f.read()
        
    orient = Quaternion(tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0,0,0))
    
    for num in xrange(0,12):
        item_name = "product_{0}_0".format(num)
        print("Deleting model:%s", item_name)
        delete_model(item_name)
        
    for num in xrange(0,12):
        bin_y   =   2.8 *   (num    /   6)  -   1.4 
        bin_x   =   0.5 *   (num    %   6)  -   1.5
        item_name   =   "product_{0}_0".format(num)
        print("Spawning model:%s", item_name)
        item_pose   =   Pose(Point(x=bin_x, y=bin_y,    z=2),   orient)
        spawn_model(item_name, product_xml, "", item_pose, "world")
```

But the services never start,

```
josh@jUbuntu:~/ros/stockroom_ws$ rosrun stock_bot spawn_products_in_bins.py
Waiting for gazebo services...
```

Could not find any topics with `/gazebo/spawn_model` or `/gazebo/delete_model` even with `rostopic list`

PS: I'm running a gazebo simulation during the whole time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246419/gazebo-spawn_model-from-.py-source-code/) by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm running a gazebo simulation during the whole time.

I suspect that you run the gazebo ^ using `gazebo` command.

You need to run gazebo_ros instead.. Try :

```
rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo
```

Then you can find the gazebo services and topics when you call rostopic list and rosservice list.

PS: Make sure you've called `roscore` first

**EDIT:**

First, spawn and delete are services NOT topics. So you must check it using rosservice NOT rostopic!

When you `rosservice list`, the service you'll see is `/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model` NOT `gazebo/spawn_model`,
which means that `gazebo/spawn_model` is NOT the correct service name. Therefore you should

change this line below

```
rospy.wait_for_service("gazebo/spawn_model")
```

to

```
rospy.wait_for_service("gazebo/spawn_sdf_model")
```

AND this line below

```
spawn_model = rospy.ServiceProxy("gazebo/spawn_model", SpawnModel)
```

to

```
s = rospy.ServiceProxy("gazebo/spawn_sdf_model", SpawnModel)
```

---

Originally posted by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) with karma: 582 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-25**:
Yeah, tried that. These are the topics listed

```
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

No sign of `/spawn_model` :(

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-25**:
Of course `gazebo_msgs/SpawnModel` shows up after `rossv list`. But that does not mean its 'ACTIVE' or the server is up, does it?

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-25**:
First, spawn and delete are service , so you suppose to check it using rosservice

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-25**:
When you rosservice you will see that there are : `gazebo/spawn_sdf_model` so in your code instead of `gazebo/spawn_model` it should be `gazebo/spawn_sdf_model`

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-25**:
@r0josh I edited my answer.

**Comment by [r0josh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28227/r0josh/) on 2016-10-26**:
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "Could not find any topics with /gazebo/spawn_model or /gazebo/delete_model even with rostopic list" part stuck out to me.  The services (such as /gazebo/delete_model ) are listed when you call

rosservice list

ie, use **rosservice**, not rostopic, to check if the spawn/delete services are available.

---

Originally posted by [ElizabethA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26773/elizabetha/) with karma: 120 on 2016-10-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1